# app for running VPN configurations (NapsternetV, HTTP Injector SSH...)

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, configuration

I need a VPN connection to access filtered content on the internet because there are so many filtered content in my country.
I use nebstrent V and HTTP injector on Android.
Is there an app or any other solution to connect to these configurations in Ubuntu?